# Capybara and poltergeist 'select' text input

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

I want to position my cursor in an input field using capybara and poltergeist. (There is some javascript which fires once the cursor has been in one of the inputs which then makes the submit button appear).

Can't work out how to do it...
Sure it must be stupidly simple.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe clicking in the input should put the cursor there so

```
page.find(:field, <id, name, or label text of field>).click
```